# Nginx location doesn't match

Tags: regex, nginx, proxypass

I have an url like this:
`https://www.vagrant.something.com/cdn/util/thumb/100/100/dev-profile-images/444ba5eacba004cb31dabbb5d5cda3ce9b2c84f4.jpg`
and I have a nginx configuration with location like this:

```
location /cdn/ {
  proxy_pass http://cdn-vagrant.something.com/;
}
```

My problem is that it should execute the proxy_pass to get back the image, but location doesn't match with the URL, what is the problem? If I am using this:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://cdn-vagrant.something.com/;
}
```

And open the link it is working correctly, but in this case it proxy_pass the all request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash:

```
location /cdn/ {
  proxy_pass http://cdn-vagrant.something.com;
}
```

That way request uri will be passed to backend as is.

When `proxy_pass` contains path (even a single `/`), that path replaces the location path (`/cdn/` in your case) in proxied request.

UPD:
Your backend (cdn-vagrant.something.com) is configured to return permanent redirects for `/cdn/ -> /`. That means your `proxy_pass` directive was correct, you should pass `/cdn/` requests to `/` on backend. This *should* work:

```
location /cdn/ {
  proxy_pass http://cdn-vagrant.something.com/;
}
```

The only thing that I'm not sure about is those `if` blocks in your www.vagrant.something.com config. Try testing without them, because [`if` is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). And you should avoid blocks like `if (-f $request_filename)` and `if (!-e $request_filename)`, maybe use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) instead.

Comment: I tried it, and I tried every case what you can imagine, Do you want to look my all configuration?

Comment: I solved it, create a defult server which listening on 80 port and take proxy_pass to it, and it is working. But I don't know why, when the all communication on the 443 port. Nevermind it is working.